# calculate rating score to number

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, algorithm

I have 5 stars, and each time a user can choose to rate from 1-5. so I have array of score like this

`stars = [0,0,2,3,5]` // I have this in database

2 user rated 3 stars, 3 users gave 4 stars and 5 user gaved 5 stars, but how do I calculate the score to show in the client side?

Comment: Do aggregation of your stars array and calculate average.

Answer (score 4):

You could sum the weighted values and divide by the count of the ratings.

```js
var stars = [0, 0, 2, 3, 5],
    count = 0,
    sum = stars.reduce(function (sum, item, index) {
        count += item;
        return sum + item * (index + 1);
    }, 0);
   
console.log(sum / count);
```

Comment: The result should be 4.3, not 3.3 ... it says _2 user rated 3 stars, 3 users gave 4 stars and 5 user gaved 5 stars_

Comment: Well, not anymore ... +1

Comment: "Functional is the new bluetooth" and everybody knows ["everything's better with bluetooth"](https://youtu.be/H_lf8_pxg2Q?t=7). What wrong with [weighted average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) - does the concept need to shy away from the programming gimmicks of the day?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: "sorry, what do you mean?" Well, grumpy old man, I guess. The "sins" of the answer (otherwise correct... umm.. ed): using a functional approach (map a function over elements when a simple cycle would do), using one-letter var names (have to thing: what the hell is `r`, `a`, `i`?), no explanations which of them act as "weights" and which are the elements to be averaged (I'm not surprised the answer needed corrections). Would OP make the link with the weighted average by himself, he would't have asked... yet s/he receives a high cuisine prepared fish which works like magic, not a fishing lesson.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that works just as well but might be easier to understand.

```js
var stars = [0, 0, 2, 3, 5],
    count = 0,
    sum = 0;

stars.forEach(function(value, index){
  count += value;
  sum += value * (index + 1);
});

console.log(sum / count);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the complete solution for you.. If not works please comment..

HTML

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
stars = [0,0,2,3,5]

var sum = stars.reduce(add, 0);
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
var text='';

 for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) { 
  text += "The percentege of the star "+(i+1)+ " is :"+ (stars[i]/sum)*100 + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

Follow here...https://jsfiddle.net/zoux6v1x/1/ for details

Answer (score 0):

```js
var stars = [0, 0, 2, 3, 5];

var sum = stars.reduce(function (sum, item, index) {
    return sum + item * (index + 1);
}, 0);

var count = stars.reduce(function (count, item) {
    return count + item;
}, 0);

console.log(sum / count);
```